# How do you solve this limit? $ \lim_{x\to \infty} x(e^{2/x} - 1 ) $

Tags: calculus

I was going through studying with L'Hospital's rule, and went through this question. I've tried hard to solve it, but always couldn't go through all the way to the answer...

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x(e^{2/x} - 1 ) $$

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? thanks

Comment: It's an indeterminate form type $\infty\cdot0$, so use L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Hint: change $x$ into $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: $e^{2/x}=1+\frac2x+\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is by considering $x= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$. Therefore we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to \infty}x\left(e^{\frac{2}{x}}-1\right) &= \lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{2}{x}}-1}{\frac{1}{x}} \\
&=\lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{-2}{x^2}e^{\frac{2}{x}}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} \\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} 2e^{\frac{2}{x}} \\
&= 2
\end{aligned}
$$
the second of equation of which is due to L'Hospital's rule.

---

Alternative solution without using L'Hospital's rule:

Simply by the linear approximation: $\lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$, which is denoted by $e^x-1 \sim x$. Subtituting with $x = \frac{2}{t}$, we have $e^{\frac{2}{t}}-1 \sim \frac{2}{t}$, hence

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x\left(e^{\frac{2}{x}}-1\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty}x \cdot \frac{2}{x} = 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x(e^{2/x} - 1 ) $$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(e^{2/x} - 1 )}{\frac{1}{x}} $$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-\frac{2e^{\frac{2}{x}}}{x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$ ($\frac{\infty}{\infty}\Rightarrow$L'hopital)
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} 2e^{\frac{2}{x}}$$
$$2\cdot 1$$
$$2$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{6} + \ldots & \Rightarrow \exp\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) = 1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{2^{2}}{2x^{2}} + \frac{2^{3}}{6x^{3}} + \ldots\\\\
& \Rightarrow \exp\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) - 1 = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{2^{2}}{2x^{2}} + \frac{2^{3}}{6x^{3}} + \ldots\\\\
& \Rightarrow x\left[\exp\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) - 1\right] = 2 + \frac{2^{2}}{2x} + \frac{2^{3}}{6x^{2}} + \ldots
\end{align*}

**BONUS**

If we make the change of variable $u = 1/x$, we get that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left[\exp\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) - 1\right] = \lim_{u\to 0;u\in(0,\infty)}\frac{\exp(2u) - 1}{u - 0} = (\exp(2u))'\Biggr|_{u = 0} = 2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I solve this limit as $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\left(1+\frac2x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)-1\right)=2.$

Answer (score 0):

welcome to MSE. another idea is a substitution like below
$$x\to \infty \\ \frac1x \to 0\\ y=\frac1x \to 0$$now rewrite $$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to \infty}x\left(e^{\frac{2}{x}}-1\right) &= \lim_{ y \to 0}\frac{e^{2y}-1}{y} \\
&= \lim_{ y \to 0}\frac{(1+\frac{2y}{1!}+\frac{(2y)^2}{2!}+...)-1}{2y}\\
&= \lim_{ y \to 0}\frac{y(\frac{2}{1!}+\frac{4y}{2!}+...)}{2y}\\
&= 2
\end{aligned}$$